# Pandas read_csv skiprows=1 skips entire file

Tags: python, pandas

I am calling pandas `read_csv(... skiprows=1)` and instead of skipping the first row it's skipping every line. I suspect it's because there's an issue with the line ending character it expects vs what is there.

Does anyone know how to make this more robust?

<EDIT> My file uses \r\n, but when I set `lineterminator='\r\n'` I get "only length-1 line terminators supported"

Comment: What is the line ending character in this file? \r, or something similar?

Comment: Well, yeah, you need to know the delimiter

Comment: Use `lineterminator` as parameter of `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With file: `open("test.csv", "wb").write(b"one,two,three\r\nfour,five,six\r\n1,2,3\r\n4,5,6\r\n")`, `pd.read_csv("test.csv", skiprows=1)` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Let Python handles the line terminator with [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) using:

```
with open('data.csv', newline=None) as fp:
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: So much of this feels wrong. I can't check whether it works atm but this feels like anything other than "robust"

Comment: Python can detect automatically some line terminators, Pandas can't. Pandas cannot handle correctly `\r\n` (C engine)

Comment: It's not a line terminator, it's a delimiter

Comment: If Pandas skip all rows while you set only one it's because it detects only one line.

Comment: `newline=None` is the default, so no need to specify it.

Comment: `"a";"b";"c"` good luck splitting that based on newlines. It's still a valid CSV despite its name mentioning "comma"

Comment: @wjandrea. I wanted to be explicit that's why I used `newline=None`.